# Ruby indent on Vim with dots

Tags: vim

I have noticed that some vim distributions like janus automagically add some dots/marks for ruby indenting e.g.

```
 .....module Models
 .......class User < Base
```

I did try some ruby `.vimrc` examples for ruby but I don't seem to find something similar.

Is there a simple way to have this without having to use a full vim distribution e.g. with a simple `.vimrc` configuration ?

Comment: The simple way would be to set `listchars` for leading spaces. But that's not supported. Only trailing spaces could be highlighted with `listchars`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with: `set list listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:·`, it will show all trailing tabs and spaces with dots.

Comment: thank you ! seems indeed to be the same of the janus pre-configuration (or at least visually it seems so) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If `:echo has("conceal")` returns 1 then your vim is compiled with and can use conceal. Then you should be able to use

```
set conceallevel=1
syn match Conceal /\s/ conceal cchar=·
hi Conceal guibg=black
```